# Add to correct list in a container based on Base class type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a container class that contains many lists of objects that all inherit from a common base class. How can I add to this class if I only have the base type? Performance is critical so I would like avoid unnecessary casting.

```
class Base {

}

class A : Base {

}

class B : Base {

}

class C : Base {

}


class Container
{
    List<A> listA = new List<A>();
    List<B> listB = new List<B>();
    List<C> listC = new List<C>();

    public Add(A a) => listA.Add(a);
    public Add(B b) => listB.Add(b);
    public Add(C c) => listC.Add(c);
}


Container container = new Container;
Base base = someFactory.DoSomething(); // Returns an instance of a, b, or c.
container.Add(base);
```

Comment: _"Performance is critical"_ - isn't it for everyone? What have you tried? You could add an overload `Add(Base base)` and using the `as` operator and a null check add it to the appropriate list.

Comment: Your example looks suspiciously like a DI container. What is the reason you are not using one?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a single list in your container `List<Base>` and a single `Add(base base)`. If you need to later check the type of an item in that container, you can do it with `if(item is A)`

Comment: This is one of those cases where polymorphism is not being used the way it should be. You're "downgrading" your parameter type to a shared base type and therefore losing track of which derived type is being used. But you actually want to _remember_ the specific derived type so that you can make decisions based on that. When `DoSomething()` returns an instance of A,B or C, that means that you're expected to handle this returned object **without** knowing if it's A,B or C. Yet you want to know exactly which type it is. Your expectations conflict with what you're actually doing.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius: Solutions like `if(item is A)` are the _quickest_ way to solve the current issue with minimal code changes. However, these issues often stem from wrongly using polymorphism to oversimplify a particular algorithm. A better solution would be to improve the design of the types used so that the needed information (which derived type is being used) doesn't get lost in the first place.

Comment: @Flater: Yes, I agree with what you're saying and I'm looking to improve this design. My problem is that I am losing the derived type but I'm expected to maintain these derived objects in separate lists due to performance. I'm trying to find a better way to improve the container or how to change the overall design.

Comment: @caspnet Is there a purpose to storing separate A B and C lists? Could you not simply store one single list of Base?

Comment: @Flater I will need to retrieve a list per derived type that is stored in the container class. For example, container.GetListA().

Comment: @caspnet Noted. Why does DoSomething() return a variety of types? Can that be changed? Why don't you know in advance whether you'll be receiving an object of type A, B or C? (Based on this and the previous answer, the best solution should be clear)

Comment: @Flater I'm using a factory (following the factory pattern) to instantiate an object based on a provided enum.  For example, Base base = someFactory.Create(TypeEnum.A); I don't know what this enum is in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

1- Merge `listA`, `listB`, `listC` into single collection: `List<Base>` and merge `Add` methods to `Add(Base b)`

2- Merge `Add` methods to single method:

```
public Add(Base base) {
  if(base is A a) listA.Add(a);
  else if(base is B b) listB.Add(b);
  else if(base is C c) listB.Add(c);
  else throw new NotImplementedException()
}
```

3- Change `DoSomething` method to generic:

```
Container container = new Container;
container.Add(someFactory.DoSomething<A>());
```

I have no idea about your scenario, but IMO the last option will be faster.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing as #3. It's not about the speed, but this is the correct design. The factory must return a concrete object of the specific type, not the base type. So we need a separate factory function `DoSomething()` to return each type. It can be a generic function as you suggested `DoSomething<A>()` or it can be a function with a different name `DoSomethingA()`.